# Strange edge seams when subtracting a cylinder from other shapes

Tags: unreal, unreal-5, csg

I'm just starting with UE 5.1 and I'm noticing weird behavior when I use cylinder to subtract from other shapes. I tried adding more sides to make it smoother but these weird artifacts still persist in both editor and in gameplay. Is there maybe some rendering setting I have to enable/disable or some other trick?

[image: Screenshot showing jagged light coloured triangles around cylindrical hole]